# Can node.js be used to create Atom packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, atom-editor

I want to create an atom package which requires the use of sockets.Since it can be easily achieved using node.js with socket.io i wanted to ask if i can use it to create my package.

Comment: Atom is a hack-able text editor. Packages allow you to add extra functionalities to it.

Comment: “Atom is a desktop application built with HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and Node.js integration” – so, the answer is yes